# detect pulse objective c

Tags: ios, input, arduino

At the moment i'm creating an iOS app which is visualizing port status of an arduino. Therefor the iPad is receiving information via Serial Cable from Arduino.
The Arduino sends every 100ms a package with it's current port status. This status is visualized on the iPad.
The Ports are input Ports. I've recognized that the device i'm reading is pulsing the ports so the Arduino reads high low level alternating. That creates flickering in the visualization.
My question is now how to detect if the level is up or the input is flickering.
The port is high for x seconds get low for y seconds and after that it repeats. If the port is low for z seconds i need to set the port as low in the visualization. Otherwise it is high.

```
- (void) readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)numBytes {
int bytesRead = [manager read:rxBuffer Length:numBytes];

 if(rxBuffer[i]==48){
        [self setButtonRed];
    }else if(rxBuffer[i]==49){
        [self setButtonWhite]
        }
    }
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhy5lbm8lkdhnoy/3wire.png?dl=0

Comment: So you have "flicker" because you have floating inputs? Well, IMHO the best solution is.. Don't leave them floating. Use either a large (e.g. 100 kOhm) pullup or pulldown. Then implement a sort of debounce directly in the arduino code, so the readings will be more "stable".

Comment: the flickering is because the device i'm reading is changing the output port to an input port to read in a button state which is connected to the same port. There is an LED and a button connected the technology is called three wire.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhy5lbm8lkdhnoy/3wire.png?dl=0

Comment: i'm using a optocoupler to read the state of the lines ten to one. The optocoupler is connected parallel

Comment: First of all I hope there is a limiting resistor in series with the LED ;) Anyway soyou put an optocoupler on the line towards contact 1, ok, and I assume that you connected the the other side of the coupler to the arduino. Ok. Now, the coupler usually have just a transistor as output stage. How did you connect it?

Comment: i've connected the opto like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ver2nwzzexwouer/opto.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well the scenario is this: you want to determine if the output is alternating its state or it is stuck at ground. You didn't specify the period/up-low time nor the number of pins, so I assume that you have four buttons connected to arduino pins 1,2,3,5 and I'll use literals.

You'll have to set `CHECK_PERIOD` to an appropriate sampling period so that you can sample the input 4/5 times for every state, and `CHECK_ITERATIONS` so that you can also miss some points.

For instance if the normal wave is 100ms high and 100ms low, I'd set `CHECK_PERIOD` to 20 and `CHECK_ITERATIONS` to, let's say, 3 or 4.

```
long previousInputCheck;
#define NUM_INPUTS 4
const int inputPins[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5}
unsigned char inputCounter[NUM_INPUTS];
unsigned char inputStates[NUM_INPUTS];

... THEN, INTO THE MAIN ...
if ((millis() - previousInputCheck) >= CHECK_PERIOD)
{
    previousInputCheck += CHECK_PERIOD;
    unsigned char i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++)
    {
        if (digitalRead(inputPins[i]) == LOW)
        {
            if (inputCounter[i] <= CHECK_ITERATIONS)
                inputCounter[i]++;
            if (inputCounter[i] == CHECK_ITERATIONS)
            {
                inputStates[i] = LOW;
            }
        }
        else
        { // HIGH
            inputCounter[i] = 0;
            inputStates[i] = HIGH;
        }
    }
}
```